# How can I import the data from a text file into the mysql database using mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, import

Is there any way other than "LOCAL DATA INFILE" to import the data into the Mysql database. I amusing mYsql workbench. Is there any way to import the data using workbench. let me know any other way which is very easier than using LOCAL DATA INFILE.

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 0):

Loading a CSV or other data file is currently not supported by MySQL Workbench.

However if you have a dump of database then you can import in through workbench. On main screen see 'Manage Import/Export'.

Other methods may be 'Load data infile' query or using mysqlimport.exe

Comment: While I am trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE giving error ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/aaa.txt' (Errcode: 2)

Comment: This shows that MySQL is unable to read the file.
Please check the permissions of your file and directory (in which the file is placed) and make it readable to all.